# Checking if a table exists in HiveQL (through SAS) and perform operation

Tags: hive, sas

I am trying to make my code more dynamic by performing operations only when a table exists. I know for a fact that while dropping table, 'if exists' statement works.

```
proc sql  NOERRORSTOP;
connect to hadoop (Server=&HDP_Server. port = &port.);
execute (drop table if exists SCHEMA1.XYZ) by hadoop;
disconnect from hadoop;
quit;
```

I want something similar to work when I am creating a backup of table or while appending. Both the following statements run into errors when my table XYZ is not present.

Appending query ( I need just ABC to be appended if XYZ is not present):

```
proc sql  NOERRORSTOP;
connect to hadoop (Server=&HDP_Server. port = &port.);
execute(create table SCHEMA1.APPENDED_DATASET as
    select * from 
    (select * from SCHEMA1.XYZ UNION ALL 
    select * from SCHEMA1.ABC
    ) unionresult
)
by hadoop;
quit;
```

Backup query ( I do not want the backup file to be created if XYZ does not exist):

```
proc sql  NOERRORSTOP;
connect to hadoop (Server=&HDP_Server. port = &port.);
execute(create table SCHEMA1.XYZ_BACKUP as
    select * from SCHEMA1.XYZ

)
by hadoop;
quit;
```

Is there a way I can do select * if exists from the table XYZ so that I do not run into errors?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know HiveQL at all.  Is there a way to select from metadata/dictionary tables to identify the presence of a table proactively, rather than try/catch like you seem to be going about above?

Comment: I think I can try that. The metadata way. Thanks!